# File upload drag and drop with dropzone.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to implement a drag and drop feature to upload a file. And it's working. What I don't understand is why I can't make it to limit the filesize and the file extension. I have the code for it, I think, but it just won't do it.

In the cshtml page:

```
<script src="~/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
        accept: function (file, done) {
            if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
                done("Naha, you don't.");
            }
            else { done(); }
        }
    };
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div id="dropzone">
            <form action="Upload" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="uploader">
                <div class="dz-message needsclick">       
                    Drop files here or click to upload.<br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "images");
    if (file.Length > 0)
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

    return RedirectToAction("About");
}
```

I mean, the code is given by them, I have the dropzone.js and the dropzone.css like they tell us to do and still... The thing is, it's working. It uploads, goes to the code behind. Everything. I just can't apply those limitations, even though they are there...

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the options on a different Dropzone than the form.  [From the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage):

> Dropzone will find all form elements with the class dropzone, automatically attach itself to it, and upload files dropped into it to the specified action attribute.

So your `<form>`, with class `dropzone`, is automatically set up as a Dropzone.

[Again from the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration), to set options on a Dropzone, you use `Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {}`, where:

> // "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID

In your code, you're using `Dropzone.options.dropzone`, so you're applying those options to a Dropzone with id `dropzone`.  In your HTML, that's a `<div>`, not your existing `<form>` Dropzone.  So when you drop a file onto your `<form>`, those options you've specified are not relevant - they're for a different Dropzone (which is actually never instantiated)!

Get rid of your `<div id="dropzone">`, and change the identifier on your options to `Dropzone.options.uploader`, so they apply to your form Dropzone.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess didn't understand it well enough. Thanks for clearing it up. :)

Comment: @taiko Glad to help :-)  Actually you don't need to remove your `<div>`, maybe you're using it for layout etc - just updating the options identifier is enough.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I just updated the options identifier. Hadn't seen that. Thanks. :)